# How to update table in ASP.NET MVC 5 Razor Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 5 Razor and I need some help how can I upload rows in my database.

I also use EF6 existing database for my model.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
@if (Request.QueryString["GetUser"] != null && Request.QueryString["Update"] == "Open")
                            {
                                ViewBag.Notification = "Do you want to sync " + @Request.QueryString["GetUser"].ToString() + " to ActiveDirectory2?";
                            }
                            @if (Request.QueryString["GetUser"] != null && Request.QueryString["Update"] == "Update")
                            {
                                using(GWActiveDirectory.Models.GW_UTAEntities db = new GWActiveDirectory.Models.GW_UTAEntities())
                                {
                                    var query = "UPDATE ActiveDirectory2"
                                              + " SET SamAccountName = '" + DataStorage.Rows[0][0].ToString() 
                                              + "', EmployeeNumber = '" + DataStorage.Rows[0][9].ToString()
                                              + "', GivenName = '" + DataStorage.Rows[0][4].ToString() 
                                              + "', Surname = '" + DataStorage.Rows[0][1].ToString() 
                                              + "', EmailAddress = '" + DataStorage.Rows[0][5].ToString() 
                                              + "', Enable = '" + DataStorage.Rows[0][3].ToString() 
                                              + "', Guid = '" + DataStorage.Rows[0][2].ToString()
                                              + "', SID = '" + DataStorage.Rows[0][6].ToString() 
                                              + "', DateCreated = '" + DataStorage.Rows[0][7].ToString() 
                                              + "', DateModified = '" + DataStorage.Rows[0][8] + "'"
                                              + " WHERE SamAccountName = @SamAccountName";
                                    db.ActiveDirectory2.SqlQuery(query,Request.QueryString["GetUser"])
                                    db.SaveChangesAsync();
                                    Response.Redirect("?SearchString=" + ViewBag.searchString + "&GetUser=" + Request.QueryString["GetUser"]);
                                }  

                            }
```

But the problem is when I try to run my program the table `ActiveDirectory2` didn't update.

Comment: At THAT level - mixing up half a dozen terms and technologies so that even the headline makes no sense (there is no "ASP.NET MVC 5 Razor Database") I would seriously suggest a book, some online tutotrials, like on asp.net. Once you at least know the basic terms and how mvc seems to work in general we can help a lot better. THis is way beyong "i have a specific problem " in the "hey, i have no frekaing idea what I am doing" teritory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SqlQuery` is for querying. For updates you need to use `ExecuteCommand`. **However** you seem to want to use EF in which case you don't stitch SQL queries manually but you fetch the entity from the database you want to update, you set the properties and you call `SaveChanges`. Also note that in your code snippet the `SaveChanges` call does not make sense because it is a no-op. Because you bypass EF when updating the database the context does not track any entities so `SaveChanges` does nothing.

Finally the way you create your command is susceptible to a **SQL injection** attack. If you use EF the right way EF will build the command securely.